# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement a JQuery autocomplete text box. I couldn't get my custom one to work, so I'm trying to implement the stock text box instead to begin with so I can fix this error. I'm not sure where this is coming from considering that I have included all of the files which the page(https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) has suggested. Except the demo css file, but this doesn't matter as the css shouldn't intefere with the functionality of the text box.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Content/ClientDash.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
              "ActionScript",
              "AppleScript",
              "Asp",
              "BASIC",
              "C",
              "C++",
              "Clojure",
              "COBOL",
              "ColdFusion",
              "Erlang",
              "Fortran",
              "Groovy",
              "Haskell",
              "Java",
              "JavaScript",
              "Lisp",
              "Perl",
              "PHP",
              "Python",
              "Ruby",
              "Scala",
              "Scheme"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
```

Layout:

```
<head>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `jquery library` before `jquery ui`

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsuumL7g/)

Comment: Have that in my layout too, still not the problem. I'll update my question with the layout file

Comment: I have that, check the answer

Comment: try to change jquery ui version/jquery library and check if that solves

Comment: check that libraries are loading sequential and proper in `HTML tab` in `mozilla firebug`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87478/discussion-between-rakesh-sadhula-and-andrew-kilburn).

Comment: thanks man. I had been looking for 3 hours. Finally I saw your post. Placed jquery ui as you said. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the beginning of your code with the one below. You are missing some files.

```
<title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


    <script>
        $(function () {
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, sorry I should have explained. I'm using a layout file which already has a more up-to-date JS file. And I also don't need the style.css file.