# jQuery autocomplete not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have spent many hours trying to figure out what is preventing the jQuery autocomplete function from working so would really appreciate any help. I am getting the following error in IE and a similar one in Chrome and Firefox:

JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

From what I have researched I understand that this is due to a js reference file but none of the solutions I have seen have worked. Here are the references to the js-ui and general js file:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Custom data and display</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
</head>
```

And here is where I implement it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#school").autocomplete ({
                minLength: 2,
                source: schools,
                select: function (e, ui) {
                    e.target.value = ui.item.label;
                    $("#schoolValue").val(ui.item.value);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
</script>
<input id="school" class="register-field" placeholder="School" type="text" />
```

This has been driving me absolutely crazy so I again appreciate any help!

Comment: can u post sample of what "schools" is? do you see any errors on console?

Comment: what do you have in the variable "schools", array of string?

Comment: schools is an array of universities (label) with their database id's as the value. In the console in chrome it says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function"

Comment: Did you verify the path of the jquery, jquery js files <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

Comment: Do you have any _404 Not Found_ console messages regarding jQuery UI? It sounds like jQuery UI is not being loaded properly, perhaps from an incorrect path...

Comment: @Rolwin: yes I have.

Comment: @War10ck: no I do not have any 404 errors in the console

Comment: Close your document ready function `});`. I'm surprised you're not getting _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"_ because of this. Are you sure this is the exact code that you're having an issue with?

Comment: Please try replicating your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It works perfectly in a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#school").autocomplete ({
            minLength: 2,
            source: schools,
            select: function (e, ui) {
                e.target.value = ui.item.label;
                $("#schoolValue").val(ui.item.value);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="school" class="register-field" placeholder="School" type="text" />
```

Comment: @Christian It still sounds as though jQuery UI is not loading properly. Add `alert($.ui.version);` as the first statement in your document ready block. If the version number is not shown in the alert box, then jQuery UI is failing to load properly...

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116618/uncaught-typeerror-autocomplete-is-not-a-function