# jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function at fire jquery-1.10.2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am working on an MVC 5 Application which got written in 2014 and was using older versions of JQuery and as such some functions have been deprecated and as a result, through the use of Google Chrome's Developer Tools via F12 hot key, I keep getting these console errors. I have imported `JQuery library` before `JQuery UI` according to these two SO posts:

[Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116618/uncaught-typeerror-autocomplete-is-not-a-function) and [TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300586/typeerror-autocomplete-is-not-a-function) as shown below but this attempt still does not remedy the problem.

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/js/custom/general.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery.jgrowl.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/js/plugins/jquery.alerts.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/js/custom/elements.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/js/plugins/colorpicker.js")"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

**General.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    //search box of header
    jQuery('#keyword').bind('focusin focusout', function(e)
    {
        var t = jQuery(this);
        if(e.type == 'focusin' && t.val() == 'Search here') 
        {
            t.val('');
        }
        else if(e.type == 'focusout' && t.val() == '')
        {
            t.val('Search here');   
        }
    });

    jQuery( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
}
```

And the above produces an:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function

```
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (general.js:373)
at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3048)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3160)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:433)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:104)
```

My search box is not even showing and I am suspecting its a result of these errors I keep getting.

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` and then `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>`. Don't include jQuery twice. Include the more recent version, and include it _once_, _before_ all the other scripts. In other words, delete the reference to 1.9.0. Then see if you still have a problem. Including it twice can cause weird conflicts.

Comment: Also `.bind` was superseded by `.on` in jQuery 1.7, and deprecated in 3.0. Use `.on` for forward compatibility and better functionality.

Comment: Lastly, unless you have just made a typo in your example here, you need to include `jQuery( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({` _inside_ the "document.ready" function. otherwise there's a danger the code will run either before the jQuery libraries are loaded, and/or before the element it targets is rendered to the browser. There also seems to be a `);` missing from the end of the "document.ready" function, which makes me wonder if it's just typo here.

Comment: @ADyson Please mark your comment as an answer. It actually removed the error. Thank you.

Comment: Simply place the .autocomplete code inside jquery.ready block

Comment: @Harold_Finch thanks I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to correct:

1) `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` and then `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>`. Don't include jQuery twice. Include the more recent version, and include it once, before all the other scripts. In other words, delete the reference to 1.9.0. Then see if you still have a problem. Including it twice can cause weird conflicts.

2) `.bind` was superseded by `.on` in jQuery 1.7, and deprecated in 3.0. Use `.on` for forward compatibility and better functionality.

Comment: It was a typo - it is inside the document.ready function @ADyson

Comment: Ok thanks, I will remove that part of the answer; I see you've edited your code.

Answer (score 1):

this is caused by conflicts between different version of jQuery. You may try to change to function like this(from http://blog.verysu.com/article/328):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$(function () {
   $............... 

});});
```

Comment: I spent a solid day trying to figure this out and your solution was the only one that worked.... thank you